# angularjs constant value return values as object

Tags: angularjs

i have assigned angular constant value is

app.constant('API':'localhost');

but it return the value as below

```
{...}
     build: function name()
    cancel: function waitForInterim()
    destroy: function destroyInterimElement()
    hide: function waitForInterim()
    show: function showInterimElement()
    __proto__: Object { … }
```

Comment: it should be comma, app.constant('API'`,`'localhost');

Comment: ya i did that but also same response

Comment: i don't see any issue works fine here https://jsfiddle.net/YHn4b/192/ . you use it to replicate .

Comment: @MahendranB same, working here : https://plnkr.co/edit/HvpfMFkUoClEvWk0ML23?p=preview

Comment: Could you paste your controller code, where you are injecting constant?

Comment: in a controller, how did you call "API"? Paste controller code